# How to read floats from file in C

Tags: c

The file looks like this:

```
A 0.0213457
B 0.0928375
C 0.1837314
D 0.0938231
E 0.7263910
```

Does the following code not look for only floats?

```
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
     fscanf(letFloats, "%f", &floats[i]);
}
```

It seems like it can run more than 26 times, and its storing large decimals

Comment: **Always** check the return value from `scanf` and `fscanf` to confirm they scanned as many values as you asked them to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to skip over the string at the beginning of each line.

```
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
     fscanf(letFloats, "%*s %f", &floats[i]);
}
```

The `*` means to parse the string, but not store it anywhere.

Your code isn't storing anything, because `fscanf()` always fails to find a float to parse.

Comment: Ahh, I figured the problem had something to do with the letters. Thanks a bunch!